# How to parse a string to date using dateformatter in objective c

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter, ios9

I have a string '2015-06-23T15:43:04.000+05:30' and i want to convert a date format like 23 June 2015 15:43

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: @Paulw11
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:replace];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM YYYY"];
    dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];

After that i got null .I dont know what happening their.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one's:

```
NSString *temp = @"2015-06-23T15:43:04.000+05:30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+05:30'"];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:temp];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", dte);

NSDateFormatter *dF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dF setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dF stringFromDate:dte]);
```

In Console:

Date: 2015-06-23 12:43:04 +0000

23 June 2015 15:43

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-01-01 11:11:11"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-06-23T15:43:04.000+05:30"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSDateFormatter *dF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dF setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString2 = [dF stringFromDate:dte];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-06-23T15:43:04.000+05:30"];


[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```